# undefined reference to `mingw_initcharmax'

Tags: cmake, mingw, mingw-w64

I want to develop a program with gtk4. The environment is MinGW64 on Windows.

My CMakeLists.txt is as folowing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(AOMAPP C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK4 REQUIRED gtk4)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK4_LIBRARY_DIRS})



add_executable(AOMAPP
        main.c
        )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(AOMAPP
        ${GTK4_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

But have those error messages:

```
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initcharmax[.refptr.mingw_initcharmax]+0x0): undefined reference to `mingw_initcharmax'
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltssuo_force[.refptr.mingw_initltssuo_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `mingw_initltssuo_force'
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltsdyn_force[.refptr.mingw_initltsdyn_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `mingw_initltsdyn_force'
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_initltsdrot_force[.refptr.mingw_initltsdrot_force]+0x0): undefined reference to `mingw_initltsdrot_force'
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.mingw_app_type[.refptr.mingw_app_type]+0x0): undefined reference to `mingw_app_type'
```

Recently, I move this program to a new PC.(that is running OK on original PC.)

Answer (score 0):

I modify CMakeLists.txt as this way, it's running

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(AOMAPP C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK4 REQUIRED gtk4)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK4_LIBRARY_DIRS}) # commented out



add_executable(AOMAPP
        main.c
        )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(AOMAPP
        #${GTK4_LIBRARIES} # commented out
        ${GTK4_LINK_LIBRARIES} # added
        )
```

Someone know why?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).